# HTTP ERROR when trying to upload images from the wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I am getting an HTTP ERROR when trying to upload images from the wordpress backend.
Tried a few suggestions of finding the php.ini file but unable to do so via SSH.

Also tried adding the below code

```
function ms_image_editor_default_to_gd( $editors ) {
    $gd_editor = 'WP_Image_Editor_GD';

    $editors = array_diff( $editors, array( $gd_editor ) );
    array_unshift( $editors, $gd_editor );

    return $editors;
}
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'ms_image_editor_default_to_gd' );
```

Which did not help.

I am using an Ubuntu instance on Amazon Lightsail, Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $gd_editor = 'WP_Image_Editor_GD';

    $editors = array_diff( $editors, array( $gd_editor ) );
    array_unshift( $editors, $gd_editor );

    return $editors;
}

Did the job

Comment: Could you share your apache logs to check the HTTP ERROR better?